# Automatically Pull Blog Post From Contentful using GatsbyJs and Cloudflare Workers

Tags: gatsby, contentful, cloudflare-workers

I Just wanna know if there is a way to automatically get Blog Posts from Contentful every time a new blog is added. My site is Hosted on Cloudflare Workers and I use GatsbyJs as the SSG.

Answer (score 1):

Contentful DevRel here.

The way to make that is using [web hooks](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/webhooks/). Web hooks are requests that contentful makes whenever something changes to a URL that you define.

So, whenever you update the Contentful you could let your CI (continuous integration) pipeline know via HTTP and rebuild/redeploy the Gatsby site to Cloudflare. This is a very common approach for JAMstack sites like Gatsby.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Hi @stefan, thanks for the reply, I'm very very new to this so i don't know where to start. Perhaps you can help me how to implement this to my work? Any help will be truly appreciated :)

Comment: 1. Find out where the Gatsby site is built
2. See if the build can be triggered via HTTP (with a webhook) and find out the URL
3. Go into contentful in 'settings -> webhooks' and define the webhook to be sent on publish events.

I'm not a cloudflare expert and don't know where/how you're building/creating the site. :) But these three steps usually do the job. :)